# How would you calculate the velocities for particles bouncing off eachother?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I have made this piece of code using canvas to portray some particles that fight over their designated color. Currently I have made the particle "put" their colors on the other particles, if they collide and I've also made them "suck" the other particles' mass, if within a certain radius. I want to take it to the next level by also, when a ball have hit another ball, make them bounce away from each other, by somehow negating the velocity in a way that has something to do with the relative angle to the other particle. How would one implement this? I can't quite wrap my head around this, although I study science in high school.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/dremp/pen/fzxvK?editors=001

This is the snippet that detects if particles have hit eachother.

```
function update() {
    paintCanvas();

    for(var i = 0; i < Particles.length; i++) {
        p = Particles[i];

        p.x += p.vx;
        p.y += p.vy;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, false);

        var drawMethod = (fillParticles === true) ? 'fill':'stroke';

        ctx[drawMethod]();
        ctx[drawMethod+"Style"] = p.color;

        if (p.x + p.radius > W || p.x - p.radius < 0) p.vx = p.vx * - 1 + 0.05;
        if (p.y + p.radius > H || p.y - p.radius < 0) p.vy = p.vy * - 1 + 0.05;

        if      (p.x + p.radius > W) p.vx -= 0.05;
        else if (p.x - p.radius < 0) p.vx += 0.05;

        if      (p.y + p.radius > H) p.vy -= 0.05;
        else if (p.y - p.radius < 0) p.vy += 0.05;

        for(var j = i + 1; j < Particles.length; j++) {

            p2 = Particles[j];

            var disance,
                distanceX = p.x - p2.x,
                distanceY = p.y - p2.y,
                color;

            distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

            if(distance <= p.radius + p2.radius) {
                p2.color = p.color;
                color = p.color;

                var ax = distanceX / 1000,
                    ay = distanceY / 1000;

                p.x += ax;
                p.y += ay;
            }
            else if(distance <= p.radius * 2 + 50) {
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = p.color;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
                ctx.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();

                p.radius += 0.005;
                p2.radius -= 0.005;

                if(p.radius > 50) p.radius -= 0.01;
                if(p2.radius < 5) p2.radius += 0.01;
            }
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
```

Comment: This is more a physics question firstly. You should determine if you want to use 'elastic' or 'inelastic' collisions, where in the first kinetic energy is conserved and in the second some kinetic energy is lost in deformation etc. I would suggest going with the first (as it is easiest) and google elastic collisions and conservation of momentum. The equations are relatively easy and you can transform those into code

Comment: Google 'physics collision angle' turned up this which you can turn into Js http://m.sparknotes.com/physics/linearmomentum/collisions/section2.rhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate impulse:

```
               // Find normal from other to me

                normX = p.x - p2.x;
                normY = p.y - p2.y;

                // make into unit vector

                normLength = Math.sqrt( normX * normX + normY * normY);

                normX = normX / normLength;
                normY = normY / normLength;

              // Get projection of movement vectors onto normal
              // (Dot prod each with norm)

              myProj    = (p.vx * normX) + (p.vy * normY);

              otherProj = (p2.vx * normX) + (p2.vy * normY);

              // Now, factor in impulse, derived from
              // Conservation of Energy / Conservation of Momentum

            impulse = ( 2 * (myProj - otherProj) );

            p.mass = 1; // Replace with "mass" calculation (based on area?)
            p2.mass = 1;   
            impulse = impulse / (p.mass + p2.mass);


          p.vx = p.vx - (impulse * p2.mass * normX);
          p.vy = p.vy - (impulse * p2.mass * normY);

          p2.vx = p2.vx + (impulse * p.mass * normX);
          p2.vy = p2.vy + (impulse * p.mass * normY);
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/gengel/pen/pFHGa

If you have different balls of different sizes flying around, you should change those p.mass lines to reflect that (area would probably work - (pi * r)^2 )

(edited to replace "P" with "impulse" since P was taken)